# How to setup C++ compiler in CLion IDE for macOS

Tags: c++, clion

I try to setup C++ compiler in CLion for macOS X.
But I've got stuck with the installation of configuration of compiler and debugger.
Every time when I try to execute code, I catch an error

```
file iostream is not found
Undeclared identifier std
```

Who can help me to get started with CLion C++ compiler
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't use the native ide Xcode?

Comment: CLion is not a compiler, it is an IDE. Have you installed a compiler?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I have Xcode, but I don't know how to add it in Clion

Comment: Did you check out, and follow, [the tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-macos.html)?

Comment: @molbdnilo Now I install Xcode compiler but downloading time every second is increasing, so I don't know what to do

Comment: CLion isn't very integrated if you have to install the compiler separately. Did OP try [following the instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-macos.html#installproc)? It is not required to install full-blown XCode.

Comment: @sweenish I have the following error when I added I working directory

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app -o main /Users/mykhailolapshyn/Desktop/Clion/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX/main.cpp

Comment: Extra information should be **edited** into the question. You also didn't answer my question.

Comment: Cannot run program "/Applications/Xcode.app" (in directory "/Users/mykhailolapshyn/Desktop/Clion/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX"): error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Although, not that information. I have no idea what you're trying to do with that command. Just follow the instructions that have been posted in the comments twice now. Setting up a proper C++ environment is not trivial.